# A basic proof: $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\left.\right|b$ then $a^2\left.\right|b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I must state whether the following is true or false on my homework (yes, this is a homework problem, so I would appreciate it if you would only give hints or suggestions and not write out the total solution):

> For all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\left.\right|b$ then
>   $a^2\left.\right|b^2$.

I believe it to be true, but I have only tried numbers $0<a<b<30$ in my head and I wrote a simple program to test all $ 0<a<b<10000 $ that I think is right, so I think it's true. But how do I prove this? This is what I have:

> *Proof:* Let $a,b$ be integers such that $a\left.\right|b$. Then \begin{align} al=b,\:\:\text{s. th.}\:\:l\in\mathbb{Z}.\tag{1}
>  \end{align} If $a^2\left.\right|b^2$ then  \begin{align} a^2
> l^2=b^2,\tag{2} \end{align}

which tells me there must exist a squared number multiple of $a^2$ to equal $b^2$. But is this always true?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You want to prove $\ ak=b\,\Rightarrow a^2 x = b^2\,$ for some integer $\,x.\ $ Can you see how to transform the first equation into the form of the second, so obtaining a solution for $\,x?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I believe that by squaring both sides of $\left(1\right)$ I would arrive at $\left(2\right)$, but then $l$ is just some integer since the set of integers is closed under multiplication, which is why you have said $x=l^2$. So I suppose this is proven from merely squaring both sides?

Comment: Yes, you got the hint, congratulations! $ $ (I used the notation $\,k\,$ for what you call $\,\ell)\ \ $

Comment: It's very common for beginners to start as you did: “If $a^2\mid b^2$ then…”, but it's wrong. You can't take what you have to prove as the hypothesis. In this case the hypothesis can be written $al=b$ and you want to find $L$ such that $a^2L=b^2$. Manipulate $al=b$ to reach the conclusion by finding a suitable $L$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That makes sense. I'll make sure I do not make this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that argument you've already prove it, but aparently you don't realize about it. To realize what it's happening, think carefully about the link between the statements (1) and (2).

Comment: No, because the OP's statement "if $\,a^2\mid b^2\ $ then ..." is incorrect.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see that it is incorrect to say that now.

Comment: I mean, the statement (2) is actually what you want to reach, from (2).

Answer (score 0):

if $a|b$ then $b=ak$ for some k

$b^2=(ak)^2=a^2k^2$ so this is always true

Comment: (S)He said only hints.